# Email code verification view not returning to index page or confirming email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

Hi guys i have the code below that: creates a code that will be sended to a user mail with a link that redirects to the view to confirm its email by inserting the Code(generated and sent to the user mail) until now works fine the problem is that once posted the form the email is not confirmed and the redirect view can't be found.Please help i can't figure out why it doesn't show any apparent error and why it does simply nothing.

> ConfirmEmail.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using xxxx.Data;
using xxxx.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account;
using System.Text;

namespace xxxx.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
    {
        public string verificationCode;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ConfirmEmailModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
          public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string userId,string code)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                var e = user.Email;
                StringBuilder VerCode = new StringBuilder();
                Char[] generator = e.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    VerCode.Append(generator[i]);
                }
                if (verificationCode == VerCode.ToString())
                {
                    if (userId == null || code == null)
                    { 
                    return RedirectToPage("/StartPage");
                    }

                    if (user == null)
                    {
                    return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
                    }

                    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Error confirming email for user with ID '{userId}':");
                    }
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("StartPage", "Users");
            }
                else {
                ViewData["Error"] = "Your verification code is wrong!";
            }
                //if failed
            return Page();
          }        
    }
}
```

> ConfirmEmail.cshtml

```
@page
@model ConfirmEmailModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Confirm email";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<div>
    <form method="post">
    @if (ViewData["Error"] != null) {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('@ViewData["Error"]');
            }); 
        </script>
     }
    <h4>Write your verification code here:</h4>
    <input type="text" asp-for="verificationCode">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"asp-action="/CodeVerification">Confirm your Account!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

> What happens (some immages): The email that recives the user!
>   [image]
>
> The link from the mail message that redirects to confirm mail redirect!

[image]

> The error + EmailConfirmation and redirect to StartPage not done!

[image]

Please guys help me i have literally no clue .

Comment: asp-action="/CodeVerification" what if you remove the /

Comment: stll it does nothing it doesn't exist as a action i just forgot it there  the problem is that the code inside onpostasync is not executed.

Comment: seems like you should remove this: asp-action="/CodeVerification"  The form is already going to post and there is no CodeVerification page.